# How to find Start date from time elapsed as percentage and End date in java

Tags: java, java-8, timestamp, localdate

i have below code

End date = 31 oct 2024 and
elapsedPercentage  is 10% of total duration on current date

as per above  params

expected Start date value  is 12 aug 2023

but i am getting 07 Dec 2023 from below code

```
 public static Timestamp calculateStartDate(double elapsedPercentage, Timestamp endDate) {
    try {
        
        LocalDate endDates = endDate.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
        long elapsedDays = (long) (endDates.lengthOfYear() *((100 - elapsedPercentage) / 100.0));
        LocalDate startDate = endDates.minusDays(elapsedDays);
        return  Timestamp.valueOf(startDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, avoid legacy class `java.sql.Timestamp`. Replaced years ago by the modern *java.time* classes, specifically `Instant`.

Comment: 10% of the current date, so 10% of 24 hours?  _24 ⨯ 0.1 = 2.4_.  Or are you saying that 10% of the total duration will have occurred on the end-date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are calculating with the `lengthOfYear`. You should calculate the days between now and end date, which represent `(100 - elapsedPercentage)%`. You can do that by using [DAYS.between()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method from [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html). With that you can easily get the number of days to subtract from now to get the start date. Something like:

```
public static Timestamp calculateStartDate(double elapsedPercentage, Timestamp endDate) {

    LocalDate end    = endDate.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
    LocalDate now    = LocalDate.now();
    long daysBetween = DAYS.between(now, end);
    long toSubtract  = (long) (elapsedPercentage * daysBetween / (100 - elapsedPercentage));
    LocalDate start  = now.minusDays(toSubtract);

    return  Timestamp.valueOf(start.atStartOfDay());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this modification, the code should give you the expected start date of "2023-08-12" when you provide an elapsed percentage of 10% and an end date of "2024-10-31."

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public static Timestamp calculateStartDate(double elapsedPercentage, Timestamp endDate) {
    try {
        // Convert the Timestamp to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = endDate.toLocalDateTime();
        
        // Calculate the total duration in days (from end date to one year later)
        long totalDurationDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(endDateTime.toLocalDate(), endDateTime.plusYears(1).toLocalDate());
        
        // Calculate the elapsed days based on the percentage
        long elapsedDays = (long) (totalDurationDays * (elapsedPercentage / 100.0));
        
        // Subtract the elapsed days from the end date
        LocalDate startDate = endDateTime.toLocalDate().minusDays(elapsedDays);
        
        // Create a Timestamp from the start date at midnight
        return Timestamp.valueOf(startDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thnks for quick response, here endDates.minus is giving compile time error "The method minus(TemporalAmount) in the type LocalDate is not applicable for the arguments (double)"

Comment: The error you're encountering is because the minus method of LocalDate expects a TemporalAmount as its argument, not a double. To calculate the new LocalDate by subtracting a fractional number of days, you can convert the double to a long representing the number of days and then use it as a TemporalAmount. I updated answer.

Comment: This gave me 2024-09-25 where the OP asked for 2023-08-12.

Comment: I edited , check please. @OleV.V.

Comment: I still get the same result. I don’t think your edit makes any difference. I suspect you may not have understood the requirements correctly. They certainly were not clearly described in the question,so that would be no wonder.

Comment: @OleV.V. sorry for misunderstanding, i edited now.